# How to remove a record from an XML response with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

The XML response below is an example of a response from Amazon for one of their APIs. It includes 2 records. I need to figure out how to remove the record from the XML doc if the status is "ClientError" or if it includes an Error node..either one would work. I am using Nokogiri in a Rails project. Any ideas of how to remove it from the XML doc if either of those conditions exist?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForASINResponse
  xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="1933893445" status="ClientError">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>ASIN 1933893445 is not valid for marketplace ATPOWSJGJFNC</Message>
  </Error>
</GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
<GetMyPriceForASINResult ASIN="1933890517" status="Success">
  <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
           xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>1933890517</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <Offers>
      <Offer>
        <BuyingPrice>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>303.99</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>300.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>3.99</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </BuyingPrice>
        <RegularPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>300.00</Amount>
        </RegularPrice>
        <FulfillmentChannel>MERCHANT</FulfillmentChannel>
        <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
        <ItemSubCondition>Acceptable</ItemSubCondition>
        <SellerId>A1IMEXAMPLEWRC</SellerId>
        <SellerSKU>SKU2468</SellerSKU>
      </Offer>
    </Offers>
  </Product>
</GetMyPriceForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>a3381684-87bd-416e-9b95-EXAMPLE9c236</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForASINResponse>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reduce your sample XML to a basic, minimal, example that demonstrates the problem, and show a minimal example of your code. Asking us to write code for you isn't cool, and any code we write will be unrelated to anything you've written, making it more difficult to incorporate into your code.

Comment: If *any* node has a `<error>` sub-node or does the `<error>` node have to have a parent node with `status="ClientError"`?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
# xml is initialized to XML string given in the question

doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search("[status='ClientError']").remove
puts doc.to_xml
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">

<GetMyPriceForASINResult ASIN="1933890517" status="Success">
  <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>1933890517</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <Offers>
      <Offer>
        <BuyingPrice>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>303.99</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>300.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>3.99</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </BuyingPrice>
        <RegularPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>300.00</Amount>
        </RegularPrice>
        <FulfillmentChannel>MERCHANT</FulfillmentChannel>
        <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
        <ItemSubCondition>Acceptable</ItemSubCondition>
        <SellerId>A1IMEXAMPLEWRC</SellerId>
        <SellerSKU>SKU2468</SellerSKU>
      </Offer>
    </Offers>
  </Product>
</GetMyPriceForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>a3381684-87bd-416e-9b95-EXAMPLE9c236</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForASINResponse>
```